# jQuery checkboxes checked when posting data

Tags: jquery, forms, post, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes on a page and when the page is loaded for the `first` time I would like them all `checked` by default.

However, once a user de-selects certain boxes and then submits the page (it posts back to the same page) I'd like their selections to be shown and not all checkboxes checked by default.

Currently I have the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.sdate').attr('checked', true);          
});
```

This checks the checkboxes but I can't work out the logic to then only show then users selection when the `post back` happens.

Comment: You'll have to keep record of what's been checked, either in a db or through local storage. For example, if there are 15 checkboxes, make yourself a 15 character long string of 1s and 0s.. then you can iterate through them and re-check boxes by index and the position in the string.

Comment: And why aren't you just setting the elements `checked` attribute based on the POST'ed data on the serverside ?

Comment: Set ids for all checkboxes say c1,c2,c3 etc. Send all ids of checkboxes whichever checked as query string and get those ids in next page load and set checked=true for only those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any server side language like php or any other you can try like this, php example.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">

   $( document ).ready(function() {
      var was_posted = <?php echo ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
      if(was_posted != true){
         $('.sdate').attr('checked', true);  
      }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Pleasure helping you.